# div background across the entire length

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to have a background which spreads inbetween two other backgrounds?
So you basicly have 3 background images; a top part, the middle part which the length of can vary by div length and a bottom part.

Like in this image

[image]

Comment: because I need all the space to put my content in, the backgrounds are perfectly gonna overlap eachother, but I do not want to deform the top part and bottom part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question properly, you want the background to be of three different colors.

You could achieve this using `linear-gradient` on the `#container`.

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
#container {
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #9C84E2 10%, #9C84E2 20%, #00F37A 20%, #00F37A 80%, #00F37A 80%, #FF6081 80%);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.</div>
```

Comment: Nicely done, sir! You can probably drop the inside elements since OP wants to write content across the whole container.

Answer (score 0):

Simply create three divs and apply different backgrounds to each.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this?

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="top"></div>
   <div class="middle"></div>
   <div class="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.top{
    width: 100%;
    height: 20%;
    background: blue;
}

.middle{
    width: 100%;
    height: 60%;
    background: green;
}

.bottom{
    width: 100%;
    height: 20%;
    background: red;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/f5vnts57/)

Comment: This is good, but top and bottom probably need to have fixed height.

Comment: exactly like this, but I need my content to go in the entire box

Comment: @Azrael what do you mean by entire box?

Comment: im not following. The parent div is `.wrapper`. Can you explain this a different way?

Comment: OP wants the content to go over all three divs, not just the middle one, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish the content to go over everything, you can sort of "fake" the background using absolute divs. See this (it will stretch across the full height, but you can change that, of course):

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
#main {
  background: green;
  height: 100%;
}
#top {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: cyan;
}
#bot {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
#content {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="top"></div>
  <div id="bot"></div>
  <div id="content">
    CONTENT HERE CONTENT HERE CONTENT HERE CONTENT HERE CONTENT HERE CONTENT HERE CONTENT HERE CONTENT HERE CONTENT HERE CONTENT HERE CONTENT HERE CONTENT HERE CONTENT HERE CONTENT HERE CONTENT HERE CONTENT HERE CONTENT HERE CONTENT HERE CONTENT HERE CONTENT
    HERE CONTENT HERE CONTENT HERE CONTENT HERE CONTENT HERE CONTENT HERE CONTENT HERE CONTENT HERE CONTENT HERE CONTENT HERE CONTENT HERE CONTENT HERE CONTENT HERE CONTENT HERE CONTENT HERE CONTENT HERE CONTENT HERE CONTENT HERE CONTENT HERE CONTENT
    HERE CONTENT HERE CONTENT HERE CONTENT HERE CONTENT HERE CONTENT HERE CONTENT HERE CONTENT HERE CONTENT HERE CONTENT HERE CONTENT HERE CONTENT HERE CONTENT HERE CONTENT HERE CONTENT HERE CONTENT HERE CONTENT HERE CONTENT HERE CONTENT HERE CONTENT
    HERE CONTENT HERE CONTENT HERE CONTENT HERE CONTENT HERE CONTENT HERE CONTENT HERE CONTENT HERE
  </div>
</div>
```